# How do I get the nearest past date in a range for each entry in another list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I collect customer feedback for my education business and add it to a Google Sheet. The feedback data has a submission date (`A2:A`) and some satisfaction metrics, which I visualize in a Google Data Studio dashboard.

The problem is that I want the feedback per cohort, but not everyone fills in the feedback form on the same day. I have a list of all courses with their respective dates (`Cohorts!A2:A`), and I want to assign each feedback submission to their respective cohort in a new column. It would be nice to also match it to the specific course type and country, but for now matching the cohort date would suffice.

I've tried using `VLOOKUP` and `ARRAYFORMULA` to go through the feedback dates and get the nearest past date to take it as the "course date" for that student. All the solutions I've tried either only take a single date or `TODAY` as a reference, but I have a whole list I'd like to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to round the timestamp, then match it to your course table?

To round a timestamp to a date:

```
=INT($A2)
```

When doing lookups like you're describing, I frequently end up calculating the nearest week as well - this formula returns the Sunday of the week start. Figured it might be helpful.

```
=text($A2+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY($A2),0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6),"m/d/yyyy")
```